# Get date equivalent of current day from last year?

Tags: .net, datetime

I am trying to find a way to get the date of the matching day from last year,

so for example today is the 4th Friday in July, what would the date of the same be last year?

I am getting the sales from a restaurant and I need to check them against last years sales on the same day.

Comment: Well, the fourth Friday in July of last year was a different date, and so you will not always be able to answer it as there are sometimes 5th <something>days in a month (Fridays in Oct of this year) that won't always be there (Oct of next year).

Comment: Also you're going to have to handle edge cases for leap years...

Comment: Maybe DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) will have to do...

Comment: @Blakomen that isn't so useful for the sales forcasting/historical comparisons Iggy probably wants to do. Iggy would probably be better off starting with getting stats on sales for each day of the week, then each day of the week for a particular month, and finding ways to narrow it down from there, but that is just a guess.

Comment: @Iggy: note that the answers will be about .NET, not about C#. C# doesn't have any support for dates.

Comment: @John Saunders are you *sure* C# has no support for Dates, or have I misunderstood your comment? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx

Comment: @Blakomen: what part of the MSDN documentation does that link point to? Right at the top, it says ".NET Framework Class Library". Here's a link to [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx). See if you see a date structure defined there. You'll find an "`int`" type that's equivalent to `System.Int32`, but you won't find a C# type equivalent to `System.DateTime`.

Comment: @Rex: When the student doesn't understand, it's up to the teachers to teach, not to just pat the student on the head and say, "that's ok, it doesn't matter."

Comment: @John Ah, I see what you mean. You are most definitely correct :) (Although really, if you're doing C#, I don't really see why you wouldn't be doing in .NET most of the time) Thanks for teaching me something!

Comment: @John and it's up to another professor to poke his head in and say "don't worry everyone, he's just an asshole" ;)

Comment: @Rex: if you really don't see the benefit in developers understanding that there are other languages that work with .NET, and that .NET and C# are not the same thing, then you're certainly welcome to your opinion.

Comment: @John: "Use this function from the BCL" IS a valid answer to the question "How do I do this in C#".  C# provides access to the BCL so it has date support not less than found in .NET.  Now, knowing it's not part of C# itself but can be used from any .NET language is definitely worth knowing, but it doesn't justify saying it isn't a C# answer.

Comment: @Ben: it's possible I'm overreacting due to the number of questions on SO that don't distinguish between the two, and the fact that so many of the questioners don't actually seem to _know_ there's a difference. Maybe this OP knows the difference and just happened to put the words "C#" in front of his title. Possible.

Comment: this question is extremely ambiguous and needs clarification: when you say "equivalent date", are you referring to 2009-07-23 when today is 2010-07-23, or are referring the same number of days since January 1st of each year? The answer will be different depending on how this clarification is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

The problem, as stated, has no answer, because months begin on different days in different years (not to mention leap year complications).

Would it be sufficient to just subtract 364 days, this is exactly 52 weeks so you end up with the same day-of-the-week?

Comment: this would work i'd think except for leap years, any way to take those into account here?

Comment: Then check that the day of the week is the same. Because leap years will push this calculation out by one day. If the day of the week is different subtract one more day.

Comment: No, they won't.  52 weeks is exactly 52 weeks.  Now, the julian date will be two different instead of one different, but this is still the occurance of the same day of the week closest to exactly one year earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is the nth particular weekday of a month in a year, this code may help:

```
using System;

class NthWeekDayOfMonth
{
    public
    NthWeekDayOfMonth(DateTime date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public
    NthWeekDayOfMonth(int n, DayOfWeek weekDay, int month, int year)
    {
        DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
        if ( weekDay < firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek )
        {
            this.date = firstDayOfMonth.AddDays((n - 1) * 7 + weekDay + 7 - firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek);
        }
        else
        {
            this.date = firstDayOfMonth.AddDays((n - 1) * 7 + weekDay - firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek);
        }
    }

    public int
    Month
    {
        get { return date.Month; }
    }

    public DayOfWeek
    WeekDay
    {
        get { return date.DayOfWeek; }
    }

    public int
    N
    {
        get { return (date.Day - 1) / 7 + 1; }
    }

    public int
    Year
    {
        get { return date.Year; }
    }

    public DateTime
    Date
    {
        get { return date; }
    }

    private DateTime
    date;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for ( DateTime d = new DateTime(2010, 7, 1); d <= new DateTime(2010, 7, 31); d = d.AddDays(1) )
        {
            NthWeekDayOfMonth thisYear = new NthWeekDayOfMonth(d);
            NthWeekDayOfMonth lastYear = new NthWeekDayOfMonth(thisYear.N, thisYear.WeekDay, thisYear.Month, thisYear.Year - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}th {1} of {2} in {3}: {4} - in {5}: {6}", thisYear.N, thisYear.WeekDay, thisYear.Month, thisYear.Year, thisYear.Date, lastYear.Year, lastYear.Date);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you fix your code? 1/6/2017 => 1/1/2016... 1/7/2017 => 1/2/2016... and then come a huge SKIP 1/8/2017 => 1/10/2016 (CORRECT). Update to see whole January/2017 and you can see the error. Thanks

Comment: There is no error; the "huge SKIP" is correct.

Jan 7, 2017 is the first Saturday of Jan 2017. The first Saturday of Jan 2016 is Jan 2, 2016.

Jan 8, 2017 is the second Sunday of Jan 2017. The second Sunday of Jan 2016 is Jan 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime sameDayLastYear = new DateTime(now.Year - 1, now.Month, now.Day);
```

You will run into a problem with a leap year i.e. the following code will throw an exception when you try to set the date to 2011-02-29

```
DateTime leapDay = new DateTime(2012, 2, 29);
DateTime sameleapDayLastYear = new DateTime(leapDay.Year - 1, leapDay.Month, leapDay.Day);
```

Comment: While that will get the same numbered day of the month, it will not get the nth <Mon,Tues,Wednes,Thurs,Fri,Satur,Sun>day as Iggy asked for.